# how guessing a birthday works

Tags: java, algorithm

I am reading an example in the "Introduction to Java Programming" by Y. Daniel Liang book
**wondering how this algorithm works behind the scene **

```
String set1 = 
    "  1  3  5  7\n" +
    "  9 11 13 15\n" +
    " 17 19 21 23\n" + 
    " 25 27 29 31";

    String set2 = 
    "  2  3  6  7\n" +
    " 10 11 14 15\n" +
    " 18 19 22 23\n" + 
    " 26 27 30 31";

    String set3 = 
    "  4  5  6  7\n" +
    " 12 13 14 15\n" +
    " 20 21 22 23\n" + 
    " 28 29 30 31";

    String set4 = 
    "  8  9 10 11\n" +
    " 12 13 14 15\n" +
    " 24 25 26 27\n" + 
    " 28 29 30 31";

    String set5 = 
    " 16 17 18 19\n" +
    " 20 21 22 23\n" +
    " 24 25 26 27\n" + 
    " 28 29 30 31";
```

he displays 5 sets , and if his birthday in this set he add the first number in the string , if not ignoring this set and continue to second set until reach set5 summing all first entry in the set if his birthday in the set

I read the explanation and couldn't understand it , so Can anyone explain how it was done , and how this sets placed ?

Comment: The code you posted defines five `String` variables which consist of concatenated literals. There is no logic here.

Comment: The code and algorithm can be found at https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/html/GuessBirthday.html . Note there are 5 "yes / no" questions. That gives 32 distinct possibilities.

Comment: A python version is at https://github.com/amandeepthakur/guessingBirthday/blob/master/birthdayGuessing.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is based on binary numbers notation.

- By asking "is the number contained in the first set?" he displays all numbers that have the 2^0 bit set. Note the response.
- By asking "is the number contained in the second set?" he displays all numbers that have the 2^1 bit set. Note the response.
- By asking "is the number contained in the third set?" he displays all numbers that have the 2^2 bit set. Note the response.
- By asking "is the number contained in the fourth set?" he displays all numbers that have the 2^3 bit set. Note the response.
- By asking "is the number contained in the fifth set?" he displays all numbers that have the 2^4 bit set. Note the response.

Now you have the responses indicating which bits are set in the birthday's binary number. Just convert the binary notation to decimal, and this can be done by simply summing up the first value of a set if the response was 'yes'.

If you still struggle to understand, make the effort and write down all numbers from a set in decimal and binary and compare the patterns.